# Can't edit categories in Magento after upgrade to 1.9.4

Tags: magento-1.9

After upgrade to Magento 1.9.4 I can create new categories but I can't edit them. Is it some missing patch?

Answer (score 0):

In your server (Vhost) file, change the @handler definition according to the following:

```
location @handler { 
    # rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?$1 last;
    rewrite / /index.php;
}
```

And add the following definition for php (in addition to any others you might have):

```
location ~ \.php/ { 
    rewrite ^(.*\.php)/ $1 last;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809272/cannot-edit-categories-in-magento-after-updating-to-1-7

Comment: Thanks. But where can I find that files in Cpanel?

Comment: usr/local/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228354/virtual-host-location-on-cpanel-server